# Java: Can't add an int to an arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist, int, addition

I've created an empty arraylist here:

```
private ArrayList<OrderItem>  conveyorBelt = new ArrayList<OrderItem>(10);
```

And in the same class, I've created a method where I add item into the conveyorBelt by inputting the orderNum (which is an int). This is what the method looks like:

```
public void addToConveyorBelt( int orderNum )
{
OrderItem oi;
conveyorBelt.add(oi.getOrderNum(orderNum)); // line 4
}
```

This doesn't work. I get a compile error on line 4, saying this: http://i52.tinypic.com/ny8n86.jpg

Anyone know where i'm going wrong with this?

p.s. - the OrderItem contains one variable called theOrderNum and a method that calls it called getOrderNum.

Comment: why do you need to get the order num from the orderitem if you already have the order num? Surely what you are trying to do is create a new OrderItem from an order num and add that to the list?

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm trying to do. I apologise for not making myself clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message, the method signature of "getOrderNo" does not accept a parameter of type "int".  From what you've given, I suspect the OrderItem class looks something like this:

```
public class OrderItem {
    private int theOrderNum;

    OrderItem(int num) {
        theOrderNum = num;
    }

    public int getOrderNum() {
        return theOrderNum;
    }
}
```

If so, you want to create a new OrderItem from the orderNum parameter, and then add it to conveyerBelt:

```
public void addToConveyorBelt(int orderNum) {
    OrderItem oi = new OrderItem(orderNum);
    conveyorBelt.add(oi);
}
```

If not, you need to update the question to include more information about the OrderItem class.

Answer (score 1):

getOrderNum obviously returns an int. Your arraylist is an arraylist of `OrderItems`. What are you expecting to happen?

Not only that, but you're guarunteed a null pointer exception there because `oi` isn't initialised.

Comment: Not entirely correct. Local variables in a method are not initialized to null if they are not assigned. Like this the compiler will complain that the variable is not initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the clear up Reboot. I was going to reply with something along those lines. Thanks anyways Falmarri.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your method should be something like this:

```
public void addToConveyorBelt(int orderNum){
    OrderItem oi = getOrderItem(orderNum);
    conveyorBelt.add(oi); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. But on line three I get a compile error saying "cannot find symbol - method getOrderNum(orderNum)". (even though you said "getOrderItem", I put "getOrderNum" because that's what the method is called in OrderItem). Know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you define arraylist like that

```
private ArrayList<OrderItem>  conveyorBelt = new ArrayList<OrderItem>(10);
```

It means you **can only add** `OrderItem` to the list

```
public void addToConveyorBelt( int orderNum )
{
OrderItem oi;
conveyorBelt.add(oi.getOrderNum(orderNum)); // here it fails
}
```

Change it as follows

```
public void addToConveyorBelt( int orderNum )
    {
    OrderItem oi = new OrderItem(orderNum);
    conveyorBelt.add(oi); // here it fails
    }
```

`oi.getOrderNum(orderNum)` should throw **NullPointerException**

Comment: Thanks hilal. This is also useful (NullPointerException part).